# How to create comment to email message with Outlook 2013?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, comments

Simply something like `mouse right click on email >> add comment/notes`

I don't see such option :/

I know I can add flags and categories to email, but there are no option to add comment text.

Comment: There's no such functionality by default in Outlook 2013.
Best way would probably be OneNote 2013, since it's highly integrated.

Comment: @Vanadis Was there ever a functionality like that in Outlook, I wonder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **Notes** section of Outlook to create a separate note you can attach to an email message. To do this, click the **…** button on the **Navigation Bar** and select **Notes** from the popup menu.
[image]
Click **New Note** on the **Home** tab of the Notes window (or press **Ctrl + N**) to create a note.
[image]
Enter the text for your note in the small note window that displays and click the **X** button to close the note, saving it.
[image]
To attach the note to the email message, make sure the **Mail** section of Outlook is active. **Double-click** on the **message** which you want to attach the note. Leaving the **Message window** open, go back to the main Outlook window and select **Notes** from the **Navigation Bar**, as mentioned above. **Drag** the note you created to the **message window**. The note is added to the message as an attachment.
[image]
When you close the **Message window**, a confirmation dialog box displays asking if you want to save your changes. To save the message with your note added as an attachment, click **Yes**.
[image]

A paperclip icon is added to the message in the list of email messages, indicating there is an attachment in the message.
[image]
When you add a note to an email message as an attachment using the Notes section of Outlook, you don’t have to keep the original note. The note is now saved with the message, and can be deleted from the Notes section.

Comment: Nothing happens when I drag the note onto the message window (Outlook 2013).  The cursor turns into a NO symbol (like the ghostbusters circle with a diagonal line). And when I close the message nothing happens.  I even tried to drag the note into the attachments area.